# Clarification on what should and shouldn't be deleted in the LQP Queue

Tags: discussion, low-quality-posts, disputed-review-audits

I failed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/11268178) audit this morning.

Ever since I read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287563/youre-doing-it-wrong-a-plea-for-sanity-in-the-low-quality-posts-queue) post by undo, I've been more careful with recommending deletion in the LQP queue.

I did think that this post was an (albeit quite bad) attempt to answer, and my usual modus operandi in the LQP Queue for those is to press "Looks OK" and then move on to the post to downvote. Seems like the audit was assuming the correct choice is "recommend deletion".

I still think this is an attempt at an answer and shouldn't have been deleted. Am I wrong? If so, why?

Comment: You voted "looks okay" on a post that got deleted 9 days ago.  Pay attention for crissake.

Comment: @HansPassant I tend to not cheese audits and judge posts by their content. And by the content that this post has, I found it to be bad yes but not delete worthy. Why is that wrong?

Comment: An unregistered user posted a dump of code, copy-pasted from another site (at least they linked to the original source), with no attempt whatsoever to make a connection between that code dump and the question being asked. You clicked "Looks OK"?

Comment: @CodyGray Its a comment of "This might help you with the problem" + some code and a source for that code. Now, its bad and somewhat doesn't adress the intricacies of the question, but its a) an obvious attempt to answer and b) not plagiarism and c) not spam. In such a case, where an answer is merely bad should I still click "recommend deletion"? I thought a Downvote would have sufficed there.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Umm... looking at the review history of that post - everyone has failed that audit...

Not the greatest of audits - when it was deleted it still had an active spam flag on it (presumably that site has come up before hence a moderator chose to delete it for that reason - don't have time to check right now) which made it eligible for being an audit. But yes, in this case, "Looks OK" is a reasonable action to take and later downvote if you wanted - it does look like an attempt to answer, has code, cites a source, and isn't blatantly spam by the looks of it (without gathering further context).

I've cleared the spam flag off the post and lifted your review ban.